# how can i get the alphabet value like F1 or F2 from keyPressEvent?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwidget

I want to print key value like ['a', 'b', ... , 'f11', 'f12']

```
def keyPressEvent(self,e):
    print(e.key())
```

but when i press f1, the function key, then it printed the value 16777264.
how can i convert 16777264 to f1?

Answer (score 2):

`key()` returns an int that can be matched using the [`QtCore.Qt.Key`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum) enum.

Qt provides F key identifiers up to F35, so you can build a simple map and check it in the key event.

```
class FKeyTest(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    fKeys = {}
    for f in range(1, 36):
        fKeys[getattr(QtCore.Qt, 'Key_F{}'.format(f))] = 'F{}'.format(f)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = self.fKeys.get(event.key())
        if key:
            print(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare it with the QtCore.Qt.Key enum. [See here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum).

`if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_F1:`

Also, if you want the name of an arbitrary key press, you can use this:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
keys = {}
for key, value in vars(Qt).items():
    if isinstance(value, Qt.Key):
        keys[value] = key

keys[16777264]
>>> 'Key_F1'
```